# javascript code to generate random images, but it is slow

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, it is running but is slow.

The images I generate with this code are used as the background of an HTML, all in a row to fill the entire window.

This code will generate random images and will write them with a document.write() when the HTML will be invoked. I tested it and it works, it fills all the browser window with different images with 100px height. But it appears to be somehow slow.

How could I optimize?

```
var x= 1; var y = 20; var incremento = 20;
function token1(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token01 = token1(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token2(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token02 = token2(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token3(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token03 = token3(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token4(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token04 = token4(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token5(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token05 = token5(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token6(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token06 = token6(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token7(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token07 = token7(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token8(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token08 = token8(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token9(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token09 = token9(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token10(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token10 = token10(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token11(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token11 = token11(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token12(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token12 = token12(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token13(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token13 = token13(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token14(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token14 = token14(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token15(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token15 = token15(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token16(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token16 = token16(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token17(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token17 = token17(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token18(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token18 = token18(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token19(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token19 = token19(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token20(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token20 = token20(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token21(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token21 = token21(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token22(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token22 = token22(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token23(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token23 = token23(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token24(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token24 = token24(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token25(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token25 = token25(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token26(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token26 = token26(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token27(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token27 = token27(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token28(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token28 = token28(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token29(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token29 = token29(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token30(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token30 = token30(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token31(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token31 = token31(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token32(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token32 = token32(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token33(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token33 = token33(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token34(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token34 = token34(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token35(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token35 = token35(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token36(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token36 = token36(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token37(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token37 = token37(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token38(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token38 = token38(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token39(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token39 = token39(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token40(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token40 = token40(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token41(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token41 = token41(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token42(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token42 = token42(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token43(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token43 = token43(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token44(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token44 = token44(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token45(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token45 = token45(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token46(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token46 = token46(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token47(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token47 = token47(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token48(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token48 = token48(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token49(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token49 = token49(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token50(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token50 = token50(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token51(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token51 = token51(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token52(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token52 = token52(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token53(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token53 = token53(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token54(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token54 = token54(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token55(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token55 = token55(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token56(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token56 = token56(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token57(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token57 = token57(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token58(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token58 = token58(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token59(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token59 = token59(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token60(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token60 = token60(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token61(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token61 = token61(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token62(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token62 = token62(x,y);
x += incremento; y += incremento; function token63(a,b) { return Math.round(Math.random()*(b-a)+parseInt(a)); } var token63 = token63(x,y);
//

function dameMuchasImagenes()
{
    document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token20+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token01+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token02+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token03+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token04+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token05+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token06+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token07+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token08+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token09+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token10+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token11+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token12+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token13+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token14+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token15+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token16+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token17+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token18+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token19+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token21+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token22+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token23+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token24+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token25+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token26+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token27+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token28+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token29+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token30+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token31+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token32+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token33+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token34+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token35+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token36+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token37+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token38+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token39+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token40+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token41+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token42+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token43+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token44+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token45+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token46+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token47+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token48+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token49+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token50+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token51+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token52+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token53+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token54+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token55+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token56+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token57+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token58+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token59+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token60+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token61+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token62+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token63+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");
document.write("<IMG SRC= files/"+token63+".jpg HEIGHT=100  BORDER=0>");    }
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a lot of functions doing the same thing. You can simplify the function to add images with a loop, also. Note that it may be slow yet because you're adding many images.

See a example based in your code:
<s>(check the code edit - I forgot two parameters before)</s>

```
var x= 1, y = 20, increment = 20;
function generateToken() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (y - x) + parseInt(a));
}
function getImages() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 63; i ++) {
        document.write('<img height="100" src="files/'+ generateToken() +'"/>');
        x += increment;
        y += increment;
    } /* this block executes 63 times */
}
```

I recommend to use the [canvas element](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/) in this case.

Comment: Excelente código, estuve pensado como hacerlo yo mismo pero no pude. soy programado junior o menos, haha, y lo que se lo aprendo observando a otras pagina o códigos ya formados. Estoy por empezar a estudiar React JS y creo que con eso cimentare mas mis conocimientos.

Comment: @Simon Good luck. 'react' is just a library, though. I see you're still beginning, but you shouldn't start learning blocks of libraries - learn JS standards first. If this solves your question, maybe you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

check out threex.terrain.js, there are some methods you could use to use perlin noise/simplex noise to make a heightmap and then convert values to colors. it even has a method to output to a canvas for your case!